# "readInBackgroundAndNotify" increases retain count of receiver

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsfilehandle

I am using `NSFileHandle` to read data from a socket. 
This is how I am creating the `filehandle`:

> filehandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:sock
>   closeOnDealloc:YES];

I am doing this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(readData:)    name:nil object:filehandle];
[filehandle readInBackgroundAndNotify];
```

I notice that, `readInBackgroundAndNotify` is increasing the `retainCount` of the `fileHandle` by 1. Hence when I release this `filehandle` once I am done reading data, the memory is not released. And hence it is trying to read some invalid data and the app is crashing. Please note that this issue is occurring in ios 4.3 but not in ios 5. 
I am removing observer before releasing the `filehandle`. Is there anything else I should be doing before releasing the file handle object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I notice that, readInBackgroundAndNotify is increasing the retainCount
>   of the fileHandle by 1.

As it likely should as a part of an implementation detail... you are asking the `filehandle` to effectively be scheduled on the background such that if data were to arrive, it will notify.

Note that `retainCount` is useless; it might have increased by 5 or 42 in this situation.  It is irrelevant.  The bottom line is that you are asking it to do something in the background and until the "stop doing stuff in background" state is reached, the object might likely still be live.

> Hence when i release this filehandle once I am done reading data, the
>   memory is not released.

Have you told the file handle to stop reading in background?  Perhaps by `close`ing it?  If not, it might likely continue.

The difference between iOS 4 and 5 is that there may be logic where the file handle notes that there are no more observers and, thus, stops reading automatically.  Again, an implementation detail that you should not count on.

Comment: I am not sure how i ask the filehandle to stop reading in the background. I tried closing the file handle before releasing it. No use though.